# Calculate UIBezierPath width and height?

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I am creating many umorphic UIBezierPaths. I need to calculate the width and the height of a UIBezierPath. How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the height with the following line of code.

```
myPath.bounds.size.height;
```

And for width...

```
myPath.bounds.size.width;
```

Comment: But keep in mind that `bounds` is the bounding box *including all control points*. If you need the *real* bounding box, you have to compute the min/max of all cubic bezier curves of the bezier path.

Comment: @MartinR can you explain more? I your point true even if I am not using control points explicitly? does iOS adds them when I am using the simple path methods ? AND I would appreciate if you could add more data. And thanks Tanner

Comment: An `UIBezierPath` always consists of a sequence of "cubic bezier curves" and @BartoszCiechanowski gave a link with information on that topic.

Comment: @TannerSilva: Your example images are not correct. A bezier curve lies always in the convex hull of the control points. Therefore the curve always lies *inside* of the `myPath.bounds` rectangle. The `myPath.bounds` rectangle can be larger than the real bounding box, but never smaller.

Answer (score 6):

For eveyrthing related to Bezier curves I can't recommend enough [this site](http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/bezierinfo/), which contains a [full chapter](http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/bezierinfo/#bounds) related to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

in swift 4:

```
myPath.cgPath.boundingBox.width
myPath.cgPath.boundingBox.height
```